# How to merge multiple html files into one with brunch.js

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, template-engine, brunch

I'm using `underscore.js` for my templates which are stored in multiple separate `XXX_tpl.html` files inside sections similar to:

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="tpl_XXX">
  <h1>hi</h1>
</script>
```

Which I am then using inside `backbone.js` views as follows:

```
render: function () {
    this.$el.html($('#tpl_XXX').text());
}
```

I am now using brunch.js build tool which nicely outputs all my libs/js/css code into several optimized files but I am having issue with managing / organizing my templates. How do I make brunch.js build tool to append all `*_tpl.html` files at the end of `index.html`? All the examples I am seeing online show how to use `brunch.js` to merge templates into `.js` files but I don't yet understand how that works (the templates are a mix of html/js and I lose both access by ID and syntax formatting/highlighting when storing templates in `.js` files).

Q1. If what I'm doing is right (multiple templates in multiple different `.tpl.html` files all appended at the end of `index.html` when built) then how do I make `build.js` merge all of that?

Q2. If what I'm doing isn't right, what's a better approach to:

- have multiple templates that are organized and easily managed
- not create additional http requests to pull / all compiled into a single file
- have easy access from backbone.js models
- want to achieve syntax highlighting in my IDE for the template markup (i.e. no JS string concatenations, etc)

Comment: Keep in mind that your underscore templates really are converted to JS functions. By precompiling them to .js and merging that with the rest of your application you don't have to do that convertion when you render. To make that work without ID access the easiest way is to look at require.js as already suggested, or browserify if you want a more painless solution ;)

Answer (score 2):

Nice question, but I don't know if you understood how underscore templates should work precisely. Let's try to clear that up first.

#### Template compilation

An underscore template *source* is any text with interpolated code. For example:

```
var myTemplateString = "hello: <%= name %>";
```

When you want to use that template, you need to **compile** it into a function first. What? Here's how it works:

```
var myTemplateFunction = _.template(myTemplateString);
```

This creates a `myTemplateFunction` which contains your template logic. In a very simplified, pseudo-code way, you can expect `myTemplateFunction` to work somewhat like this:

```
function (context) { return  "hello: " + context.name };
```

So, now you understand why you can call this function and produce a string!

```
myTemplateFunction({name: 'moe'}) // hello: moe
```

#### Using compiled templates

OK, but why do you need to compile it previously? Why not always call directly:

```
_.template(myTemplateString)({name: 'moe'})
```

Because **compilation can be CPU-intensive**. Therefore, it's **much faster** to use a pre-compiled template. You should not force the user's browser to do it! You should do it for him!

#### Delivering compiled templates

By now, you understand you don't care about delivering the **text** of your functions to your client, only the **compiled template functions**. There are many ways to accomplish that.

Brunch has a bunch of plugins for pre-compiled templates, but apparently none for underscore: http://brunch.io/plugins.html

You can use [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/docs/what-is-webpack.html) and it's [EJS template loader](http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-loaders.html#templating).

Your code would look something like this:

```
var myTemplateFunction = require('./template.html')
console.log(myTemplateFunction);
```

You can also use [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) and it's underscore template task: [grunt-contrib-jst](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jst).

Whichever you choose, they will all work similarly: they'll compile your template into a function and you'll be able to use that function. Personally, I recommend **learning webpack**!